# Как программно вызвать установщик приложения через FileProvider?

Tags: android, contentprovider

Всем привет, я столкнулся с интересной проблемой, я делаю систему обновлений приложения по воздуху и поддерживаю Android Nougat. Чтобы избежать разрешения на запись в память устройства я сохраняю скачанный apk в кэш папки приложения

```
val file = File(activity.externalCacheDir.path + "/update.apk"
if (file.exists()) file.delete()
Thread(Runnable {
    val request = Request.Builder().url(APK_URL).build()
    val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        file.writeBytes(response.body()!!.bytes())
    }
}).start()
```

В итоге apk сохраняется в `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package>/cache/update.apk`. После загрузки я пытаюсь открыть экран установщика приложений

```
val installIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
installIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
val file = File(activity.externalCacheDir.path + "/update.apk")
val path = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".updater", file)
} else {
    Uri.fromFile(file)
}
installIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
activity.startActivity(installIntent)
```

Для поддержки Android Nougat я создал провайдер

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="<package>.updater"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/update_paths" />
</provider>
```

И файл `@xml/update_paths`

```
<paths>
    <external-cache-path
        name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

При открытии установщика он вылетает с такой ошибкой

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{d20266f
>   21396:com.android.packageinstaller/u0a25} (pid=21396, uid=10025) that
>   is not exported from uid 10074

Я меняю значение атрибута `exported` на `true` в теге провайдера и при запуске приложения получаю такую ошибку

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException:
>   Provider must not be exported

Что делать, как запустить экран установщика, если он требует открытый провайдер, а `FileProvider` - закрытый?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение найдено: добавить такой флажок интенту

```
installIntent.flags += Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
```